# Что плохого в связи HTML с PHP через JS и обработчики событий?

Tags: javascript, php

Разбираю чужой код. И часто натыкаюсь на проекты, где любые запросы настройками сервера перенаправляются на index.php, а уже этот файл обрабатывает все запросы и перенаправляет пользователя туда, куда надо. И я задался вопросом: Почему редко делают, что создают HTML разметку, а когда надо связаться с базой данных, то вешают на, скажем, кнопку, обработчик события, JS'ом делаем POST или GET запрос к нужному php файлу, а уже php файл связывается с базой данных и возвращает ответ в JS?

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: кто как умеет, так и делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что Вы описали в вопросе как общую практику - называется "централизованной маршрутизацией" применительно к запросам.

Преимущества такой штуки - в том, что перенаправление делается в одном месте. Причем, во многих фремворках правила перенаправления хранятся не в коде, а "снаружи кода" - например, в базе данных, или в файлах, в которых находится информация о "зарегистрированных модулях".

При этом происходит еще и то, что называется "санитайзинг": для каждого запроса может происходить проверка, что этот запрос - "легальный". То есть, он приходит с формы, которая имеет право посылать такой то и такой то запрос.

В целом, для небольшого проекта, а тем более для учебного проекта, это всё - излишество.

В учебных прроектах как раз надо попробовать как проще, понять проблемы, которые при этом могут возникнуть, и использовать это знание в будущем.

А из ВОЗМОЖНЫХ проблем могут быть такие: DDOS атака на страницу, принимающую запросы к базе данных. SQL injection. Нечаянные ошибки, связанные с отсутствием проверки типов и длинны данных в форме. Превращение кода в "спгетти", когад форм и старниц, обрабатывающих их, становится слишком много, или, к примеру, к однйо странице обращаются несколько форм, отлисающихся деталями (напрмиер, полным и сокращенным набором полей).

Но в целом - в комментариях правы, кто как умеет - тот так и делает.

Comment: когда все ходит через "одну дверь", то ддосить значительно проще. А также сложнее разделять на микросервисы. И когда все растет и развивается, то приходится городить огород, как эти запросы разделять.

Comment: @KoVadim - мне кажется, главная причина существования "одной двери" - в том, что в CMS-ках на PHP есть пояние "рагистрации модулей", и эта "одна дверь" - это то место в коде, где проверяется, что соответсвующий модуль есть, и тогда запрос направляется на него